# empty list outside scope of onResponse volley

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley

I have a static List list, when in try to fill this list from server in the onResponse volley method, it works, but outside the scope of the Response.Listener the list becomes empty

```
public class MapsFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

static List<Train> trainsListe = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        MapFragment fragment = (MapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        fragment.getMapAsync(this);

public void parseRedis() {
            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(uri2,
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {


                        List<Train> listeTemporaire = TrainRedisJsonParser.parseData(response);
                        for (Train t : listeTemporaire)
                        MapsFragment.trainsListe.add(t);
                        System.out.println(trainsListe.size()); // size is 4 here (it works)

                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        // Toast.makeText(getActivity(),error.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                });

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

parseRedis();
System.out.println(MapsFragment.trainsListe.size()) // 0
}
```

But outside the method, for example somewhere in onViewCreated when i try to print the size of trainsListe : 0

Comment: That request is an _asynchronous_ operation. Your list won't have anything in it yet immediately after adding it to the queue. Do whatever you need to with `trainsListe` in `onResponse()`, which runs when the request has completed.

Comment: @MikeM. Can you exlplain please, what should i do with the code

Comment: I'm not sure what you want me to explain beyond what I, and the linked duplicates, already have. Your list won't have anything in it until the `onResponse()` method runs. That's not going to happen before your `onViewCreated()` method finishes. Instead, initiate whatever code relies on `trainsListe` at the end of the `onResponse()` method.